# View full filenames in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2005, and I hate the way that the tabbed interface displays the current database and filename.  It crams both together in the tab title so that most tabs end up with a name like "databas...ccountQuery.sql".  I've tried the MDI interface, but it is not much better.

Is there any way to make SSMS display the full filename, or to separate the display of the database and filename?

Comment: Not really an answer as such, but if you hover over the tab it shows the full path in a tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which pieces of information get displayed in the tab caption by changing the program options:

[image]

(This is from SSMS 2008, but I believe these options exist in 2005 as well. If not... then upgrade to 2008 -- there's no reason not to at this point, even if your databases are still 2005.)